# TCHAR объявляется сразу с лишними символами

Tags: c++, eclipse, кодировка

Создаю массив `TCHAR` следующим образом:

```
unsigned int size = sizeof(working_path) + sizeof(TEXT("\\")) + sizeof(filename) + 1;
TCHAR old[size];
_tcscat(old, working_path);
_tcscat(old, TEXT("\\"));
_tcscat(old, filename);
old[size] = '\0';
```

В программе указываю `working_path` как `C:\Intel\Logs` к примеру.
В окне дебага на третьей строке ставлю точку останова и вижу, что `old` уже имеет значение `\fЁ›*юяяяЂШ&w…3)w`. В настройках эклипса кодировку выставил `utf-8`

Может быть нужно как-то обнулить после создания?

Comment: вместо первого `*cat(old, ...)` должно быть `*cpy(old, ...)`. Или надо нуль в первый символ `old` поместить принудительно до конкатенации. Там же мусор по умолчанию.

Comment: @alexolut сделал `TCHAR old[size] = "";` Не знаю правильно ли это, но сработало. Так же сделал как вы посоветовали. Вообще правильно ли я делаюс размером и тому подобным?

Comment: Есть смысл обрамить в `TEXT()`. Можно ещё так: `TCHAR old[size] = {};`. `size` по Стандарту должен быть `const`, кстати (gcc съедает из-за поддержки массивов переменной длины (VLA)).

Comment: В стандарте ASCIIz нулевая строка должна заканчиваться нулём, поэтому тут выход из ситуации либо cpy, либо обнуление первого символа (пустая строка)  `TCHAR old[size] = {0,};` так, или так `old[0]=0` перед всеми cat, потому что память по умолчанию не является чистой.